# Spring Boot 2.0.x EntityManagerFactory Null

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, entitymanager, sessionfactory

I am trying to use Hibernate SessionFactory to get data from Mysql and tried to unwrap SessionFactory from EntityManagerFactory.

This code is perfectly working fine in Spring boot 1.5.x but not in 2.0.x

```
@Configuration
public class SessionFactoryConfig {

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Factory is not a hibernate factory");
    }
    return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
 }
}
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue? Any help would be highly appriciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add error message you are getting

Comment: Spring Boot 2.x is using Hibernate 5.2+ . Which contains a change in which the `SessionFactory` extends `EntityManagerFactory`. Due to this change this code now makes Spring Boot back off from configuring the `EntityManagerFactory` (as the `SessionFactory` is one). You have to consider do you really need the `SessionFactory`? Generally with the current state of JPA you don't really need it. If you need the `Session` use the `EntityManager` to `unwrap the session. If you really need this downgrade to a Hibernate version lower then 5.2.

Comment: You can get EntityManagerFactory from EntityManager and then do your getSessionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

As @m-deinum pointed out in the comment, if you really want to use the `SessionFactory` you can avoid creating the `SessionFactory` and use an injected `EntityManager` instance to access it directly in your repository object.

For example:

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public void saveEntity(Foo foo) {
        emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(foo);
    }

    @Override
    public Foo getEntity(Integer id) {
        return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).getCurrentSession().get(Foo.class, id);
    }
}
```

Hope that works for you.